Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) Flask application
I'm getting this error but my files do exist and I think my file structure is correct, I don't know what to do due to I've tried everything I've found on the net but it's still failing to load the css to my html base template.
This is my structure:
C:.
│   run.py
│   
├───instance
│       site.db
│       
├───jecco
│       models.py
│       routes.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───static
│       style.css
│
└───templates
        base.html

This is my base.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
      <title>MyProject</title>

  </head>
  <body>


      <header class="header">

        <div>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <a href="{{ url_for('main.home')}}">Inicio</a>
            <a href="">Catalogo</a>
            <a href="">Rendimiento</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
 
      </header>

      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  </body>

This is my css file:
.header{
     background-color: blueviolet;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
 }

I've tried moving my files to the same folders as the templates, with a styles folder instead of static and using relative and absolute paths.

Your structure, and the HTML look correct; are you sure that is the resource that causes the error?

That's what the inspect tool of google said and this is what I got on my terminal :
- [23/Oct/2024 10:29:45] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2024 10:29:45] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

The structure looks OK, and I have a similar setup which works correctly. Are you running this in the development server, or something else?

I'm running it locally with the debug mode activated:
if name == "main":
app.run(debug=True)

I've already found a way to solve this with this line of code:
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates", static_folder="../static")

after setting the static folder it worked, but remember! use the 2 points before the slash or it won't work.

The use of the two dots before each directory name just indicates that you are starting the application from a lower directory, rather than the root of the project. Which directory are you in?
